# Check if parameter is null in CosmosDB query

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

How can I check if a parameter is null in [@azure/cosmos sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos#query-the-database) when querying the database?

I've tried the IS_NULL or IS_EMPTY, either breaks the query:

```
await container.items
  .query({
    query: `
        SELECT * from company
        WHERE company.location = @location

        AND (@dateFrom IS NULL OR company.createdAt >= @dateFrom)
        AND (@dateTo IS NULL OR company.createdAt < @dateTo)

        ORDER BY company.createdAt DESC
    `,
    parameters: [
        { name: "@location", value: "Germany" },
        { name: "@dateFrom", value: new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 5)},
        { name: "@dateTo", value: new Date() },
    ]
  })
  .fetchAll();
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Message: {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":243,\"end\":245},\"code\":\"SC1001\",\"message\":\"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'IS'.\"}]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of the [IS_DEFINED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-is-defined) expressor:

```
AND (IS_DEFINED(@dateFrom) = false OR company.createdAt >= @dateFrom)
AND (IS_DEFINED(@dateTo) = false OR company.createdAt < @dateTo)
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that the IS_DEFINED function was not quite what was needed as the property is usually defined, but holds a null value.

Instead, I found the [IS_NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-is-null) function to work:

```
AND (IS_NULL(@dateFrom) = true OR company.createdAt >= @dateFrom)
AND (IS_NULL(@dateTo) = true OR company.createdAt < @dateTo)
```

Comment: That's also a good approach! Nice to know

Comment: This works for the exact requirement where I need to ignore the parameter in where condition for rest api.